# The game of life with a truly infinite board

Tags: haskell, game-of-life

The game of life is often implemented by representing the board as a 2D boolean array.  This doesn't scale very well to larger boards -- it starts to consume lots of memory, and without some separate mechanism to keep track of a list of live cells, you have to visit each board cell on each iteration.  This implementation just keeps a list of live cells to represent the board state; the board "size" is limited only by the maximum of an integer.

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Map  as M

type Coo = (Int,Int)
type Board = Map Coo Int

moveBoard::Coo->Board->Board
moveBoard (dx,dy) = M.mapKeysMonotonic (\(x,y)->(x + dx, y + dy))

countNeighbors::Board->Board
countNeighbors b =
  unionsWith (+) [ moved (-1, -1),  moved (0, -1),  moved (1, -1),
                   moved (-1,  0),                  moved (1,  0),
                   moved (-1,  1),  moved (0,  1),  moved (1,  1) ]
    where moved (dx, dy) = moveBoard (dx, dy) b

lifeIteration::Board->Board
lifeIteration b = M.union birth survive
  where neighbors = countNeighbors b
        birth     = M.map (const 1)  (M.filter (==3) neighbors)
        survive   = M.intersection b (M.filter (==2) neighbors)

glider = M.fromList $ L.map (\(x,y)->((x,y),1::Int)) ([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,2)]::[(Int,Int)])
```

Comment: If you want to compute long and large sequences of Life, you might be interested in [hashlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer was given when the reviewed code looked quite differently.

Any specific questions? Here's what stands out for me:

1. Why do `toList` in `emptyNeighbors`, then go back to `Set` again? You could simply use `Data.Set.map` there.
2. `countNeighbor` is very inefficient: the `filter` operation always iterates over all life cells, and you are calling it three times per existing cell! That's unneeded, as you only ever care about a handful of neighbourhood cells.

My idea to fix issue 2 would be to build a `Map` of the neighbour count of every cell. If you represent the board as a `Map` with only `1` cells in it, that can be done pretty efficiently using `mapKeysMonotonic` and `unionsWith`:

```
type Coo = (Int, Int)
type Board = Map Coo Int

moveBoard :: Coo -> Board -> Board
moveBoard (dx,dy) = M.mapKeysMonotonic (\(x, y) -> (x+dx, y+dy))

countNeighbours :: Board -> Board
countNeighbours b =
  unionsWith (+) [ moved (-1) (-1), moved 0 (-1), moved 1 (-1)
                 , moved (-1)   0 ,               moved 1  0
                 , moved (-1)   1 , moved 0   1 , moved 1  1   ]
 where moved dx dy = moveBoard (dx,dy) b
```

Note that usage of `mapKeysMonotonic` is only safe because the order of coordinates doesn't change when we add a constant. Effectively, this means that the library can simply replace the concrete coordinates without any internal resorting.

The iteration is then a simple matter of using `filter`, `map` and `intersection` over the result:

```
lifeIteration :: Board -> Board
lifeIteration b = M.union birth survive
 where neighbours = countNeighbours b
       birth      = M.map (const 1)  (M.filter (==3) neighbours)
       survive    = M.intersection b (M.filter (==2) neighbours)
```

Changing your formulation slightly by having a life cell with 3 neighbours "rebirth" instead of survive, as that's a bit simpler to write.

Also note that this is a bit "clever" by taking advantage of the fact that `intersection` always returns the value of the *first* `Map`, therefore I don't need to do another `M.map (const 1)` step in there.

I hope this is helpful to you.